# MyModelForm' object has no attribute 'user using django

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, django-forms, django-views

i want to create i simple django image processing .first i have create correct a django auth and multi upload images in my app.
now i want the user can select one self image from a list django form where i create and that image i get for my processing.i create something but not work.

i take that error :

```
'MyModelForm' object has no attribute 'user'
```

here the code :

views.py

```
@login_required(login_url="login/")
def myview(request):
    Myf = MyModelForm(request.user,request.POST)
    return render(request,'home.html',{'Myf':Myf})
```

forms.py

```
class MyModelForm(ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'user' in kwargs:
            self.user = kwargs.pop('user')
        super(MyModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        choices = [(obj.id, obj.upload.url) for obj in MyModel.objects.filter(user=self.user)]
        self.fields['upload'].widget = Select(choices=choices)

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ('upload',)
```

if i replace `Myf = MyForm(request.user,request.POST)` with `Myform = MyModelForm(user=request.user)` then i think list worked like this

[image list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXPyW.jpg)

but i cant take select image for image processing.

html :

```
   <form class="" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
      {{ Myform}}
    <input type="submit" name="" value="Submit">

  </form>
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `MyForm` class does not have `user` in the `__init__` method's signature, so you need to provide it as a keyword argument when instantiating the form:

```
MyForm(user=request.user,data=request.POST)
```

Comment: if i use your proposal in html i take that message `No file was submitted. Check the encoding type on the form.` and if i try to print `MyForm` then i dont take specific image in my console,i update my ask with html page

Comment: To [handle uploads](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads), you need `files=request.FILES` as well as `data=request.POST`. If you still have problems, please ask a new question, rather than adding comments.

Comment: You have already accepted my answer to this question, so nobody will see your updated question. Your new problem is different so you should ask a new question instead of editing this one.

Comment: yes you correct i create new question if you can follow me again