# 'CreateForm' object has no attribute 'user' on form validation

Tags: python, django, forms

I'm trying to create a view in order to add data to my database through a FormView. However I'm getting this no attribute 'user' error. I found how to get rid of it with a function-based view here : [MyModelForm' object has no attribute 'user using django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43459000/mymodelform-object-has-no-attribute-user-using-django) , however I still don't get how to do the same with my class-based view.

Here are my files :

views.py :

```
class CreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'restaurant/create.html'
    form_class = CreateForm
    success_url = ''

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

forms.py :

```
class CreateForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
    category = forms.CharField()
    capacity = forms.IntegerField()
    description = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
```

models.py :

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User    
class Restaurant(models.Model):
        owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        description = models.TextField()
        capacity = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

traceback : http://dpaste.com/2NTFS8H

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you post the *full* traceback? It looks like something is missing (in the source fragments provided)

Comment: i just posted it !

Comment: Ah, it's the `login_required` decorator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not supposed to use `method_decorator` with `form_valid` method. Change your view to this:

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class CreateView(FormView):
    template_name = 'restaurant/create.html'
    form_class = CreateForm
    success_url = ''

    def form_valid(self, form):
        obj = form.save(commit=False)
        obj.owner = self.request.user
        obj.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Another option is to use the `LoginRequiredMixin`.

Comment: thanks, it worked, if someone gets the same issue, don't forget to switch to a ModelForm form, else the CreateForm won't be able to be saved from the view !